# Spark CSV read issue on swedish characters

Tags: apache-spark

I have a file that has some swedish characters    . They are not correctly populated    when i read that file via spark dataframe . I tied using UTF-8 . still same  issue . Please help

```
 scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ";").option("header", 
        "true").option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").option("charset", "ISO-8859-1").load(s"$loc")
 scala> df.show(10,false)
 +-------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
 |code_id          |code_name                           |ADDRESS           |CITY      |ZIP_CODE|
 +-------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
 |123              |omega Skene                         |VarbergsvÃÂ¤gen 71    |Skene     |44444   |
 |123              |omega Hedesunda HÃÂ¤lsocentral      |HÃÂ¤lsocentralen      |Hedesunda |44444   |
 |1245             |omega Valbo KÃÂ¶pcentrum            |Valbo KÃÂ¶pcentrum    |Valbo     |444   |
```

but the expected output is below

```
 +-------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
 |code_id          |code_name                           |ADDRESS           |CITY      |ZIP_CODE|
 +-------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
 |123              |omega Skene                         |Varbergsvägen 71   |Skene     |44444   |
 |123              |omega Hedesunda Hälsocentralen      |Hälsocentralen     |Hedesunda |44444   |
```

If i apply the UTF-8 then it shows like this

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ";").option("header", "true").option("ESCAPE quote", '"').option("charset", "UTF-8").option("encoding", "UTF-8").load(loc)

df.show(10,false)

    +-------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
  |code_id              |code_name                           |ADDRESS           |CITY      |ZIP_CODE|
  +-------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+----------+--------+
 |123               |Omega Skene                       |VarbergsvÃ¤gen 71 |Skene     |4444        |
 |12345             |Omega Hedesunda HÃ¤lsocentral     |HÃ¤lsocentralen   |Hedesunda |814444040   |
```

Comment: Did you check the actual encoding of your input file using some text editor?

Comment: If i open the .csv data file  in notepad++ , it gives me correct and expected data

Comment: And what is the encoding used in notepad++? (see the lower right corner on the editor)

Comment: Yes, i see that it is UTF-8

Comment: Are you able to get correct output by setting encoding as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I saved it a text file with utf-8 and I was able to load it correctly with  `.option("encoding", "UTF-8")`

Comment: For me if i apply UTF-8 the it shows different data , but still incorrect